# CSS selector based on a:target

Tags: css, css-selectors

This is my HTML:

```
<p class="define"><a class="term" href="#jump" name="jump">jump</a> - Some description</p>
```

When the browser jumps to `#jump` I want to highlight the `.define` class. If I do;

```
a.term:target { background-color: #ffa; -webkit-transition: all 1s linear; }
```

I of course only highlight the `a`. How do I modify this to complete `p`? I tried a couple of variants like the one below, but none of them work.

`a.term:target .define { stuff here }`

`a.term:target p.define { stuff here }`

`a.term:target p { stuff here }`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vVPPy/

Comment: Good question, no good answer except for JS, it'd be nice if CSS selectors could work like xpath, using `../`... or may it wouldn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify the parent of an element using css. You will have to use a javascript alternative.

Comment: The JS alternative is to install `mouseover/mouseout` handlers using event delegation

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to determine where the user is on the page using CSS. This can be accomplished with JavaScript - If you're not trying to reinvent the wheel, I'd recommend using Bootstrap's [ScrollSpy](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy).

Answer (score 0):

Your `<p>` tag *isn't* the target of anything.  If it were:

```
<p class="define" id="something">
   <a class="term" href="#something" name="jump">jump</a> - blah
</p>
```

You could style it like so:

```
a.term:target { background-color: #ffa; }
```

but that has nothing to do with the `<a>` actually being clicked on.  You'll need to use an `onclick` handler for that, ideally adding a class to the target and styling based on that class.

Comment: Note that `:target` will not work if the user hits `www.domain.com/page.html#something` rather than clicking on the link.